# linux load balancer ping redirect to other interface

Tags: linux, networking

Im configuring centos with load balance with ip route and ip rule

```
Eth0 192.168.1.5
Eth1 192.168.5.128

[root@host1 testscripts]# ip route
192.168.5.0/24 dev eth1  scope link  src 192.168.5.128
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.5
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link 
[root@host1 testscripts]# ip route show table wan2
default via 192.168.5.2 dev eth1  src 192.168.5.128
[root@host1 testscripts]# ip route show table wan1
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.5
[root@host1 testscripts]# ip rule show
0:      from all lookup 255
32762:  from 192.168.5.128 lookup wan2
32763:  from all to 192.168.1.5 lookup wan1
32765:  from 192.168.1.5 lookup wan1
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

But the problem here when I use `ping –I 192.168.1.5 www.google.com`
The ping it goes to the second interface, 
If the second interface is down its stick there..
What to do to fix this issue

Comment: Is `ping –I 192.168.2.5` a typo?

Comment: Yes its type mistake 
Ping –I 192.168.1.5 www.google.com

Comment: The problem is solved.
resolv.conf was pointing to second interface dns ip. That’s why packets travels to second interface .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.
resolv.conf was pointing to second interface dns ip. That’s why packets travels to second interface .